# .png animation slow performance in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

i have a .png animation in my project with 700 pics and a size of 150 px x 150 px.

it works fine but everytime, the animation starts, the whole game freezes for about 0.1 sec. like its loading but i implemented the .png array in initWithSize. like this:

```
SKTextureAtlas *barrierUfoAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"BarrierUfoAnimation"];
NSArray *barrierUfoAtlasNames = [barrierUfoAtlas textureNames];
NSArray *sortetBarrierUfoAtlasNames = [barrierUfoAtlasNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableArray *barrierUfoTextures = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *filename in sortetBarrierUfoAtlasNames) {
    SKTexture *texture = [barrierUfoAtlas textureNamed:filename];
    [barrierUfoTextures addObject:texture];
}
self.barrierUfoAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:barrierUfoTextures timePerFrame:0.024];
```

and then while playing after about 1-2 min. the animation is starting.
it doesn´t need to load anything at this point, just start the animation.
is there any way to improve it?

Comment: You can have a "loading" message while all your game assets are being loaded and start your game play once done.

Comment: ok thanks but when i implement the array with the .png files are they not already loaded? could you get more specific about your idea? how to arrange that?

Comment: are you aware that 150x150 times 700 equals roughly 60 mb memory usage? It's possible you just can't fit all of this into memory at the same time, depending on other mem usage and device.

Comment: my complete folder has 7,4 mb reduced to 420 pics with 250px x 250px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **one of many ways** to preload:

```
@implementation GameScene {
SKTextureAtlas *myAtlas1;
BOOL loadingComplete;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    // the usual stuff...

    loadingComplete = false;
    [self loadMyAtlas1];
    }   

    return self;
}

-(void)loadMyAtlas1 {
    myAtlas1 = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"MyAtlasName"];
    [SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myAtlas1] withCompletionHandler:^{
    [self finishedLoading];
    }];
}

-(void)finishedLoading {
    // other stuff you might do here
    loadingComplete = true;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(loadingComplete) {
        // run game code
    } else {
        // wait for the water to boil
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that works for me. didn´t know about that preload-method.

Comment: Preload is the answer. Even though I'm populating array at start of scene animation was lagging at first time. Preload solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing a fps drop when preloading texture atlas, even though I verified in Instruments that this work is being done on a worker thread. I've also tried and wrapped it in an async block of a global dispatch queue, which doesn't help. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?